# Compiling Coffeescript with Jade :coffee filter: Will it hinder performance? Is there a way to simplify? Bare?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, pug

I'm thinking of switching to compiling my client-side coffeescript through jade's :coffee filter. The Express setup is simple and as follows (in coffeescript, which I compile via command line):

```
app.get '/coffee/:script', (req, res) ->
    script = req.params.script
    res.render "../coffee/#{script}"
```

The .jade file could be:

```
:coffee
    console.log 'hello world'
```

I have three questions:

- Are there any performance issues I should be concerned about versus precompiling the scripts via command line? I'm assuming that on server start-up (or first load?) they may take a minuscule amount of time longer, but then should be cached?
- Is there a way to automatically make jade assume the whole file should be :coffee text? This would save the the :coffee line, and from an extra indentation on each line.
- Is there a way to have jade compile the script bare without the `(function(){` wrapper? I often write my own: `(($)-> ... ) jQuery` and sometimes need to expose variables :)

Comment: why do you want to compile coffee via a jade template, just for a console.log? you should extract scripts (js or coffee) into a own file

Comment: I just used that as an example. I plan on loading all my custom javascript as jade templates. Each script / library / plugin would have its own jade file. For example, I have a lightbox/fancybox like plugin called surface.js. I write this in coffeescript, but instead of surface.coffee I would just save it as surface.jade and load it as specified above.

Comment: and what is the advantage?

Comment: I don't have to pre-compile them through another means.